# Getting python Cloud Endpoint Enum values on an Android client

Tags: android, python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I have a python class that inherits from Cloud Endpoints [Enum](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/protorpc/messages/enumclass) and is included in a [Message](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/protorpc/messages/messageclass) for transmission to an Android client.

```
class Status(messages.Enum):

    SUCCESS = 1
    NOT_IN_MATCH = 2
    ALREADY_MATCHED = 3
    FAILURE = 4
```

Is there anyway to get these constant strings ("SUCCESS", "NOT_IN_MATCH", "ALREADY_MATCHED", "FAILURE") in the Android client? I don't see them anywhere in the generated Java source code when I use [`get_client_lib`](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/gen_clients).

Note: I have seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28488232/using-an-enum-contained-in-a-cloud-endpoint-model-on-a-android-client) that gives a solution in Java. That is not applicable when using python Cloud Endpoints.

Comment: Unfortunately, there currently isn't.

Comment: @saiyr thanks for the update... Any idea if there are plans to support this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to a Google Cloud Endoints dev [this is not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44785398/getting-python-cloud-endpoint-enum-values-on-an-android-client#comment76608998_44785398) currently.

> Unfortunately, there currently isn't [a way to get these constant strings in the Android client].